# How to fetch associations with Diesel?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I'm trying to load an association from a database using Diesel. I have the following models defined:

```rust
#[derive(Identifiable, Queryable, PartialEq, Debug)]
#[table_name = "contacts"]
pub struct Contact {
    pub id: i32,
    pub firstname: String,
    pub lastname: String,
}

#[derive(Identifiable, Queryable, Associations, PartialEq, Debug)]
#[belongs_to(Contact)]
#[table_name = "emails"]
pub struct Email {
    pub id: i32, 
    pub contact_id: i32,
    pub label: String,
    pub email: String,
}
```

Now I'm trying to fetch all contacts with their associated emails using the following code:

```rust
let result = match contacts::table
    .inner_join(emails::table)
    .load::<models::Contact, Vec<models::Email>>(&self.conn)
{
    Ok(rows) => rows,
    Err(_) => return Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "Database error")),
};
```

But this is not working. The error is something about a trait bound that is not satisfied:

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 2
  --> src/db.rs:44:38
   |
44 |             .load::<models::Contact, Vec<models::Email>>(&self.conn) {
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unexpected type argument

error[E0277]: the trait bound `(i32, std::string::String, std::string::String): diesel::Queryable<((diesel::sql_types::Integer, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text), (diesel::sql_types::Integer, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text)), _>` is not satisfied
  --> src/db.rs:44:14
   |
44 |             .load::<models::Contact, Vec<models::Email>>(&self.conn) {
   |              ^^^^ the trait `diesel::Queryable<((diesel::sql_types::Integer, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text), (diesel::sql_types::Integer, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text)), _>` is not implemented for `(i32, std::string::String, std::string::String)`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <(A, B, C) as diesel::Queryable<(SA, SB, SC), __DB>>
             <(A, B, C) as diesel::Queryable<diesel::sql_types::Record<(SA, SB, SC)>, diesel::pg::Pg>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::Queryable<((diesel::sql_types::Integer, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text), (diesel::sql_types::Integer, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text)), _>` for `models::Contact`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_dsl::LoadQuery<_, models::Contact>` for `diesel::query_builder::SelectStatement<diesel::query_source::joins::JoinOn<diesel::query_source::joins::Join<schema::contacts::table, schema::emails::table, diesel::query_source::joins::Inner>, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<diesel::expression::nullable::Nullable<schema::emails::columns::contact_id>, diesel::expression::nullable::Nullable<schema::contacts::columns::id>>>>`
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please post the exact error message!

Comment: I added the error message.

Comment: The first part of the error should be clear. `load` takes 1 type parameter, but you are providing two...

Comment: Thanks. I finally figured this one out by myself. `let result =  match contacts::table
            .inner_join(emails::table)
            .load::<(models::Contact, models::Email)>(&self.conn) {
                Ok(rows) => rows,
                Err(_) => return Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "Database error")),
        }; ` The type definition must be a tuple. Only the grouping to get a nice result is now missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As resolved in the comments, `.load()` only ever takes 1 type parameter. If you are loading multiple types for each row they need to be combined into a tuple:

```
let result = match contacts::table
    .inner_join(emails::table)
    .load::<(models::Contact, models::Email)>(&self.conn)
```

When queries get more complicated, you may end up loading types like `(A, B, (C, Option<D>)` which generally reflected the nested-ness of the JOINs and SELECTs the composed the query.

You'll also notice that the `Email` records are not returned as a `Vec` but rather flat joined with their associated `Contact` records. You'll pretty much always see data yielded in flattened rows and not deserialized into complicated structures. From [`diesel::associations`](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/associations/index.html):

> In Diesel, data and its associations are considered to be separate. If you want to pass around a user and all of its posts, that type is `(User, Vec<Post>)`.

So this isn't even taking advantage of Diesels "associations". That would look something like this to get all the emails from a `contact`:

```
Email::belonging_to(&contact).load::<Email>()
```